# How do I get the IDs of the selected records so I can send each an email?

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom Object Followup
and a related list of Cases on the layout.
How do I get the IDs of the selected records so I can send each an email?
[image]

The Visual Force Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="lutd_Followup__c" extensions="CaseNoticeEmail" sidebar="true" showHeader="false" >   
<apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form >                 
        <apex:pageblock id="CaseList"> 
          <div style="margin-left: 30%;"><apex:commandLink value="Send All Email" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" action="{!doSendEmail}"/></div> 
            <br/> 
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="case" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(cases))}">                 
                <apex:column HeaderValue="Action" id="selectedCase"> <apex:inputCheckbox /> </apex:column>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Case Number"><apex:outputLink value="/{!case.CaseNumber}" target="_blank">{!case.CaseNumber}</apex:outputLink> </apex:column>               
                <apex:column value="{!case.ContactId}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!case.Status}"></apex:column> 
                <apex:column value="{!case.ContactEmail}"/>              
            </apex:pageBlockTable>            
            <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(cases))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel> 
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

And the Controller

```
public with sharing class CaseNoticeEmail {
    //public List<Case> selected{get; set;}   
    public List<Case> cases{get;set;} 
    public lutd_Followup__c followups {get;set;} 
    public lutd_Followup__c followup {get;set;}   
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController;
    private Set<String> caseIds = new Set<String>();

    public CaseNoticeEmail(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // for (Case caseSelected : (List<Case>)standardSetController.getSelected()){ 

        //     //caseIds.add(caseSelected.CaseNumber);
        // }

        followup = (lutd_Followup__c)controller.getRecord();      

        followups = [SELECT id FROM lutd_Followup__c WHERE id=: followup.id WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1]; 

        cases = [SELECT CaseNumber,ContactId, Status, ContactEmail FROM case WHERE lutd_Followup__c = :followups.id WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED ORDER BY CaseNumber];     

} 

    public PageReference doSendEmail() {
        // Get all checked id OR ALL IDs and process them
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'This is Do Mail.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
        return null;
    }
    
    public PageReference doMarkSendEmail() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

At the moment the **Send All Emails** button is a stub.

Comment: your controller needs to have a constructor for the `standardSetController` and the page needs to have `recordSetVar`; see [Visualforce in Practice - Chapter 4](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf)

Comment: @cropredy Nice Document

Comment: An overlooked masterpiece. It was how I learned the standardset controller